# How to Hide the overflow icon in Hardware menu button in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to Hide the overflow icon in Hardware menu button in my Xamarin Android app(three dots) - refer the screen shot.

How do i do this?

[image]

Comment: Remove OnCreateOptionsMenu method from your Activity. I assume you're using ActionBar. If you must show the overflow menu in the ActionBar, use Toolbar instead of ActionBar.

Comment: I do not have OnCreateOptionsMenu method

Comment: How do you get the overflow icon? Any code or xml?

Comment: No additional code, and i get this overflow icon only in Google Nexus, not on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find the overflow icon in my nexus 6, but I would like give you some suggestions:

For the xamarin android project the `Android.App.Activity` is different between the `Activity` of Java android.

We can find the source code of the `Android.App.Activity` when the activity create a menu it will call the following function:

```
// Summary:
//     Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu.
//
// Parameters:
//   menu:
//     The options menu in which you place your items.
//
// Returns:
//     To be added.
//
// Remarks:
//     ///
//     Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu. You /// should
//     place your menu items in to menu. /// ///
//     ///
//     This is only called once, the first time the options menu is /// displayed. To
//     update the menu every time it is displayed, see /// Android.App.Activity.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu).
//     /// ///
//     ///
//     The default implementation populates the menu with standard system /// menu items.
//     These are placed in the Android.Views.Menu.CATEGORY_SYSTEM group so that ///
//     they will be correctly ordered with application-defined menu items. /// Deriving
//     classes should always call through to the base implementation. /// ///
//     ///
//     You can safely hold on to menu (and any items created /// from it), making modifications
//     to it as desired, until the next /// time onCreateOptionsMenu() is called. ///
//     ///
//     ///
//     When you add items to the menu, you can implement the Activity's /// Android.App.Activity.OnOptionsItemSelected(Android.Views.IMenuItem)
//     method to handle them there.
//     ///
//     /// /// [Android Documentation] /// ///
//     ///
[Register("onCreateOptionsMenu", "(Landroid/view/Menu;)Z", "GetOnCreateOptionsMenu_Landroid_view_Menu_Handler")]
public virtual bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu);
```

This `onCreateOptionsMenu` function will be called as default. Xamarin android encapsulates `onCreateOptionsMenu` function of Java Android. I think you can override the function in you MainActivity as follows:

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The menu should be created as default.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a Particular Device and Its OS , some of them create options menu like your device but some on right corner of the top